# Javascript variabes scope in inline functions

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, inline-functions

Why is this not working as expected:

```js
$(function(){
   var datas=[[1],[3]];
   var functions=[];
   for(var i in datas ){ 
    var data=datas[i];
    functions.push(function(){
     $("div").append($("<p/>").text("data[0]="+data[0]+", datas["+i+"][0]="+datas[i][0]));
    });
   }
   for(var i in functions )
    functions[i](); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div />
```

I expect:

```
data[0]=1, datas[0][0]=1

data[0]=3, datas[1][0]=3
```

Can some one help me to understand whats going on here?

Thanks a lot,
greetings Patrick

**---------Solution-------**

`var data` is past in the scope of the function but it will still change after.

Therefor the best solutions is `bind()`:

```js
$(function(){
   var datas=[[1],[3]];
   var functions=[];
   for(var i in datas ){ 
    var data=datas[i];
    functions.push(function(data){
     $("div").append($("<p/>").text("data[0]="+data[0]+", datas["+i+"][0]="+datas[i][0]));
    }.bind(null,data));
   }
   for(var i in functions )
    functions[i](); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I expect data[0]=1, datas[0][0]=1 and i get data[0]=3, datas[0][0]=1 why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: sorry it was my mistake

Comment: if you have an answer, post it as an answer, dont include it in your question, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all about scope. Try to change

```
var data=datas[i];
functions.push(function(){
    $("div").append($("<p/>").text("data[0]="+data[0]+", datas["+i+"][0]="+datas[i][0]));
});
```

to

```
(function (data) {
    functions.push(function(){
        $("div").append($("<p/>").text("data[0]="+data[0]+", datas["+i+"][0]="+datas[i][0]));
    });
})(datas[i]);
```

Within for-loop scope value of `data` has changed. This is why when `functions` are called they use last modified value of `data`.
That's why we created a new scope where `data` and `function` live together in a friendly fashion.

Comment: I'd prefere a solution with .bind() mentioned in a duplicate flag, somehow cleaner, hwoever the above should work, anyway the question is to be closed as duplicate